# Android update textview text from ProcessBuilder thread outputstream

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

**Hi**,
I'm new to android development and trying to build an app that will run a shell command using `ProcessBuilder`.

Whenever I run the command it freezes the main UI thread, and the output comes after the process has exited.

How can I make the shell command run in a seperate thread and update textview text?

Here's my code that i want to run in a thread:

```java
process = new ProcessBuilder()
           .command("busybox", "ls", "/sdcard/")
           .redirectErrorStream(true)
           .start();
```

Comment: You have answered the question itself. The `ProcessBuilder` command should be run on a background thread, instead of the Main/UI thread. That is call the particular method under asynchronous task.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AbhishekDutt Yes, but I cannot figure out how to do this with threads. I'm new to android development.